# Echo two $variables without space?

Tags: php

I got a text file [list_of_files.txt] contaning list of files without extension e.g.

```
image_23.
image_24.
image_25.
```

I'm using POST method to add a single word to all of the lines e.g "jpg" and display the results:

```
image_23.jpg
image_24.jpg
image_25.jpg
```

The problem is that echo displays:

```
image_23. jpg
image_24. jpg
image_25. jpg
```

How i can remove spaces?

```
$files=file('list_of_files.txt');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
        foreach($files as $list)
{
    $extension = $_POST['extension'];
    echo "$list",$exstension,"";
    echo "</div>";
}
 }else{ 
?>
```

Comment: try `trim($exstension)`

Comment: note:`echo "$list"` is a pointless use of quotes. `echo $list` works just as well.

Comment: That should read as `echo "$list",$extension,"";` and not `exstension`

Comment: @Akam `trim($extension)` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trim` to trim the white space.

```
$files=file('list_of_files.txt');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
    foreach($files as $list)
    {
        $extension = $_POST['extension'];
        echo trim($list) . trim($extension);
        echo "</div>";
    }
}else{ 
?>
```

Comment: Sorted! Cheers pal! :)

Comment: that's `trim($extension)` and not `trim($exstension)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo trim($list) . trim($extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files = file('list_of_files.txt');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach($files as $list) {
        $ext = $_POST['extension'];
        $file = $list.$ext;
        echo $file;
    }
}
?>
```

This is a simple solution to it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $list.$extension;
```

You can make a trim() on $extension before to display it to be sure there is no space.

Answer (score 0):

use trim function

```
echo trim($list) . trim($extension);
```